# Image not responsive on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I try to put img responsive on Firefox but it's not work. ( but its work with chrome).
In other answer, they said that its because the height of the parents isn't define. But here, i define the parent's height.

there is an exemple of the css code.

```
> article[class^="article-"] {
  height: 630px;
  .content {
    height: 100%
    width: 100%
    img {
      max-width: 100%
      width: auto;
      height: 100%
    } 
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can we see your code's live demo somewhere or atleast put a Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

This work fine:

```
.article {
height: 100px;
display: block;
position: relative;
  .content {
    height: 100%
    width: 100%
    img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/skriming/y7vbz1fj/